# Cognitive psychology and tipping point of believing a fact.

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Can anyone suggest studies looking at the number of times participants have to hear something in order to believe something is true?

e.g. if participant A says something to X they may not believe it, but if A B C and D say the same thing to X then they will? 
Is there an equilibrium at which a subject may start to believe what is being said, or that X number of reports strongly indicates a probability an event took place.

Comment: This question lacks initial research and is [not framed in psychology or neuroscience which puts it at risk of being put on hold](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2277/why-was-my-question-closed-as-not-framed-in-psychology-or-neuroscience).